# Insert json string with field names enclosed in single quotes into postgresql as a jsonb field

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have strings representing jsons where field names and values are enclosed in single quotes, for example `{'name': 'Grzegorz', 'age': 123}`. Let's assume that I have also a table in **postgres** database:

```
CREATE TABLE item (
     metadata jsonb
);
```

I'm trying to insert rows using JOOQ. JOOQ generates the following statement:
`insert into Item values('{''name'': ''Grzegorz'', ''age'': 123}'::jsonb);` but an error is thrown:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 1: insert into Item values('{''name'': ''Grzegorz'', ''age'': 1...
Token "'" is invalid.
JSON data, line 1: {'...
```

Is there any possibility to insert json with names enclosed in single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"` or should I convert all `'` to `"`?

Thanks in advance!

Grzegorz

Comment: `{'name': 'Grzegorz', 'age': 123}` can be a valid javascript value, but not a valid [JSON](http://json.org). Blindly converting all `'` to `"` could be dangerous, just consider f.ex. `{'name': 'Gregor "Grzegorz"', 'age': 123}` (if that's a possible generated value, because that's too could be parsed with javascript). Instead, I would look into how these values are generated & search for a method to generate *valid* JSON values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Json syntax](http://www.json.org/) requires double quotes, so It is not a question of Postgres. Server accepts only valid json values.

You can use [`replace()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html):

```
insert into item 
values(replace('{''name'': ''Grzegorz'', ''age'': 123}', '''', '"')::jsonb);

select * from item;

             metadata             
----------------------------------
 {"age": 123, "name": "Grzegorz"}
(1 row)
```